# Calling a batch file to run a python script from VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, batch-file

I am trying to run a python script from a batch file. The batch file is being called through VBA.

When I run the batch file directly, I get the desired output however when I call the batch from VBA, python terminal opens but the script execution errors out saying 'My_file.xlsx'(used in python script) is not found.

Why would that happen and how to resolve?

VBA to call batch file:

```vb
Sub Run_batch()
    Dim PathCrnt As String
    PathCrnt = "Path"
    Call Shell(PathCrnt & "Batch.bat")
End Sub
```

Batch Code:

```
"Path\python.exe" "Path\Importing_data.py"
pause
```

> No file or directory found: 'My_file.xlsx'

Comment: it can be run from different folder and you may have to use full path to `My_file.xlsx`.

Comment: Since the error is from the Python script you should include ([edit]) its code. Any reason why you don't run the Python script directly from VBA with a `Shell` command?